# Scan Lines in a Log after a keyword

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I am attempting to read a system access log. I was able to extract all information that I needed but am unable to break it down into a structured format. I need to read the Log and create a field against each user defining the outcome.

Case 1 and 2 - For Successful/Unsuccessful Logins, the Resulting message is displayed in the log in the line immediately succeeding the Login Attempt

Case 3 - Unauthorized logins also result in Access Denied messages but after n lines (n>>2).

I am trying to generate a tabular output as follows :-

```
User  Outcome 

U1     Success
U2     Failure
U3     Unauthorized
```

Sample Log - deidentified data to preserve security. The comments (##) are not generated originally  - I have added them here for guidance

```
#Login Success#
2019-08-12 TRACE [000001]  :XXXXX Handler for User U1
2019-08-12 Authenticated user: U1
.
.

#Login Failure#
2019-08-12 TRACE [000099] :XXXXX Handler for User U2
2019-08-12 Access denied
.
.
.
#Authentication Failure#
2019-08-12 TRACE [0000110] :XXXXX- Handler for User U3
2019-08-12.....Log Messages
2019-08-12.....Log Messages
2019-08-12.....Log Messages
2019-08-12.....Log Messages
2019-08-12.....Log Messages
2019-08-12.....Log Messages
2019-08-12 Access denied
```

I tried the awk command as follows :-

```sh
awk '/"Handler for User"/{print $3} {i=1;next};i && i++ <= 2' | grep -i "denied|authenticated" log.txt
```

But the command fails to work as expected. I suspect this is because the username is varying. So if someone can suggest some technique, it will be great. Also, I am  new to working with file handling and awk so any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Your post lacks a [mcve]

Comment: `I am attempting to read a system access log` - post an excerpt from system access log. How is it structured? What example lines are in there? Is there anything else or only the lines you showed? In what order?  `generate a tabular output` - what should be the (full) input file  to generate such output? And: what have you tried?

Comment: Hi, Yes these are the only example lines that are left . I read in the actual system log and grepped out all unwanted log messages and created this reduced log with the 3 scenarios that I are mentioned in the way they appear on the actual log

Comment: Are the 3 scenarios in separate files? Each file has one login?

Comment: No all 3 scenarios appear in the same file and the way the log has been reduced, they will not intermix.. meaning unless one scenario ends, no other scenario will appear in log.

Comment: But you posted 3 separate code blocks? Please edit your post and post the input file that is used to generate the output you presented. From the first block you can get `U1 Success`, but nothing about U2 or U3. The "unsuccessfull login" case differs from "No authorization" case only by the number of lines between "User * Attempts Login" and "Access denied"? How many lines will be there?

Comment: Hi Kamil... Yes hats correct the number of lines is the actual difference between the Failure and Unauthorized Login. Access Denied appears after Login for Failed Login but the number of lines is not certain for Unauthorized login and the number of lines varies before Access Denied is displayed.. as I  mentioned above the number of lines is >>2 but I do not have an exact count .. As far as the Log goes, the 3 segments appear one after another but unfortunately they got formatted in this way. I will try and fix it now

Comment: please post your code and sample input or risk getting closed voted for lack of [mcve] . Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this then?

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
    /Handler for User/ { u=$NF; reject="Failure"; next }
    u && /Authenticated user/ { print u, "Success"; u=""; next }
    u && /Access denied/ { print u, reject; u=""; next }
    u && /./ { reject="Unauthorized" }' file.log
```

This can be analyzed as a simple state machine.

[image: State diagram]

Initially, we are looking for "Handler for User" and once we see that, we enter a state where we are looking for one of three possible outcomes: Successful authentication, unsuccessful authentication immediately on the next line, or unsuccessful authentication on a subsequent line. The helper variable `reject` keeps track of whether we are on the immediately following line, and doubles as the reason to print when we see "Access denied".

(State diagram designed with http://madebyevan.com/fsm/)

Comment: Thanks .. that’s a great explanation and the code works  as expected . Can you please help me understand why you did not put a print for the “unauthorized”?

Comment: It only prints when it gets to "Access denied". The `reject` variable keeps track of which reason to print when we get there.